# How to create alias for argument/parameter (bash)?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I tried to create alias for argument by putting this code into `.bashrc`

```
alias malog="/Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_error.log"
```

And I tied to call it with different commands, like:

```
tail -f malog
vim malog
```

But it didn't work.
I know that I can write alias that will work like:

```
alias tmalog="tail -f /Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_error.log"
alias vmalog="vim /Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_error.log"
...
```

But, maybe there is a way to create alias for argument/parameter?

Comment: Aliases will only work at the beginning of a line.

Comment: zsh has "global" aliases you can use like this, not bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an `alias`, you just to set a variable with the full pathname:

```
mhttpd="/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf"

tail -f "$mhttpd"
vim "$mhttpd"
```

`alias` is a shortcut for some command usually so you can use:

```
alias tail_apache='tail -f /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf"
```

and use it as:

```
tail_apache
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm gonna accept it after a few minutes, cuz I'm getting this message "You can accept an answer in 8 minutes". Again, thank you very much for your help.